# Extract probabilities and labels from FARM TextClassification

Tags: python, nlp

I have spent a few days exploring the excellent FARM library and its modular approach to building models. The default output (result) however is very verbose, including a multiplicity of texts, values and ASCII artwork. For my research I only require the predicted labels from my NLP text classification model, together with the individual probabilities. How do I do that? I have been experimenting with nested lists/dictionaries but am unable to neatly produce a simple list of output labels and probabilities.

```
enter code here


# Test your model on a sample (Inference)
from farm.infer import Inferencer
from pprint import PrettyPrinter

infer_model = Inferencer(processor=processor, model=model, task_type="text_classification", gpu=True)

basic_texts = [
               # a snippet or two from Dickens
    {"text": "Mr Dombey had remained in his own apartment since the death of his wife, absorbed in visions of the youth, education, and destination of his baby son. Something lay at the bottom of his cool heart, colder and heavier than its ordinary load; but it was more a sense of the child’s loss than his own, awakening within him an almost angry sorrow."},
    {"text": "Soon after seven o'clock we went down to dinner, carefully, by Mrs. Jellyby's advice, for the stair-carpets, besides being very deficient in stair-wires, were so torn as to be absolute traps."},
    {"text": "Walter passed out at the door, and was about to close it after him, when, hearing the voices of the brothers again, and also the mention of his own name, he stood irresolutely, with his hand upon the lock, and the door ajar, uncertain whether to return or go away."},
               # from Lewis Carroll
    {"text": "I have kept one for many years, and have found it of the greatest possible service, in many ways: it secures my _answering_ Letters, however long they have to wait; it enables me to refer, for my own guidance, to the details of previous correspondence, though the actual Letters may have been destroyed long ago;"},
    {"text": "The Queen gasped, and sat down: the rapid journey through the air had quite taken away her breath and for a minute or two she could do nothing but hug the little Lily in silence."},
    {"text": "Rub as she could, she could make nothing more of it: she was in a little dark shop, leaning with her elbows on the counter, and opposite to her was an old Sheep, sitting in an arm-chair knitting, and every now and then leaving off to look at her through a great pair of spectacles."}, 
               # G K Chesterton
    {"text": "Basil and I walked rapidly to the window which looked out on the garden. It was a small and somewhat smug suburban garden; the flower beds a little too neat and like the pattern of a coloured carpet; but on this shining and opulent summer day even they had the exuberance of something natural, I had almost said tropical. "},
    {"text": "This is the whole danger of our time. There is a difference between the oppression which has been too common in the past and the oppression which seems only too probable in the future."},
    {"text": "But whatever else the worst doctrine of depravity may have been, it was a product of spiritual conviction; it had nothing to do with remote physical origins. Men thought mankind wicked because they felt wicked themselves. "},
]
result = infer_model.inference_from_dicts(dicts=basic_texts)
PrettyPrinter().pprint(result)
#print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

All logging (incl. the ASCII artwork) is done in FARM via Python's [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) framework. You can simply disable the logs up to a certain level like this at the beginning of your script:

```py
import logging
logging.disable(logging.ERROR)
```

Is that what you are looking for or do you rather want to adjust the output format of the model predictions? If you only need label and probability, you could do something like this:

```py
...
basic_texts = [
        {"text": "Stackoverflow is a great community"},
        {"text": "It's snowing"},
    ]
infer_model = Inferencer(processor=processor, model=model, task_type="text_classification", gpu=True)
result = infer_model.inference_from_dicts(dicts=basic_texts)
minimal_results = []
for sample in result:
    # Only extract the top 1 prediction per sample
    top_pred = sample["predictions"][0]
    minimal_results.append({"label": top_pred["label"], "probability": top_pred["probability"]})

PrettyPrinter().pprint(minimal_results)
infer_model.close_multiprocessing_pool()
```

(I left out the initial model loading etc. - see this [example](https://github.com/deepset-ai/FARM/blob/master/examples/doc_classification.py) for more details)

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift and helpful response Malte - regards Mark